Image of prime ideals in non-commutative rings
Let $f: R \to S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism between two non-commutative rings without identity. Let $P$ be a prime ideal in $R$ with $\mathrm{Ker}~f \subseteq P$. Then show that $f(P)$ is prime in $S$.
Let $A'$ and $B'$ be two ideals in $S$ such that $A' \cdot B' \subseteq f(P)$. Now since $f$ is a ring homomorphism we have that $A := f^{-1}(A')$ and $B := f^{-1}(B')$ are ideals in $R$. And since $f(A \cdot B) = f(A)\cdot f(B) = A' \cdot B' \subseteq f(P)$ we have that $A \cdot B \subseteq P$. Since $P$ is prime either $A \subseteq P$ or $B \subseteq P$. Which implies either $f(A) = A' \subseteq f(P)$ or $f(B) = B' \subseteq f(P)$. Thus, $f(P)$ is prime.
In the above proof, I did not use the fact that $\mathrm{Ker}~f \subseteq P$ and $f$ is subjective. I know that my arguments are not correct. But I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. Can anyone please help me identify my mistakes?
Edit 1:
I figured out where I will be needing surjectivity. To get $f(A) = A'$ we need the surjectivity of $f$. Is this correct? Is there anywhere else we will need surjectivity?

You're right about surjectivity being necessary for concluding that $f(A)=A'$, but you also need it to conclude that $f(P)$ is even an ideal of $S$. The condition $\ker f \subseteq P$ is there to ensure that the pre-image of $f(P)$ is actually $P$. This should fill the gaps in your argument, unless I'm missing something.
While I'm at it, I thought I'd share an alternative approach I thought of. Observe that an ideal $J$ of s ring $A$ is prime if and only if $A/J$ contains no zero divisors (other than $0$). Since $f$ is surjective it induces a homorphism $R/P \to S/f(P)$ that is again surjective. From $\ker f \subseteq P$ we see that our new homomorphism is also injective and therefore an isomorphism. Using our original observation we may now conclude that $f(P)$ is a prime ideal of $S$.
